# How do I split a string into even parts then populate an array with those new strings?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am working on a program and I will be asking the user to input a string full of characters with no spaces. I will then be splitting this string up into parts of three characters each, and I would like to populate an array with these new strings of three characters. So basically what I am asking is how would I create a method that takes an input string, splits it up into separate parts of three, then populates an array with it.

```
while (i <= DNAstrand.length()-3) {
DNAstrand.substring(i,i+=3));
}
```

This code will split the string up into parts of three, but how do I assign those values to an array in a method?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static ArrayList<String> splitText(String text)
{
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    String temp = "";
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(count < 3)
        {
            temp += String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)); 
            count++;
            if(count == 3)
            {
                arr.add(temp);
                temp = "";
                count = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    if(temp.length() < 3)arr.add(temp);//in case the string is not evenly divided by 3
    return arr;
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
ArrayList<Strings> arrList = splitText(and the string you want to split);
```

Comment: How would I go about passing my string into this method from main? I believe your solution will work I am just having trouble doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through and add all the inputs to an array.

```
    String in = "Some input";

    //in.length()/3 is automatically floored
    String[] out = new String[in.length()/3];

    int i=0;

    while (i<in.length()-3) {
        out[i/3] = in.substring(i, i+=3);
    }
```

This will ignore the end of the String if it's length isn't a multiple of 3. The end can be found with:

```
String remainder = in.substring(i, in.length());
```

Finally, if you want the remainder to be part of the array:

```
    String in = "Some input";

    //This is the same as ceiling in.length()/3
    String[] out = new String[(in.length()-1)/3 + 1];

    int i=0;

    while (i<in.length()-3) {
        out[i/3] = in.substring(i, i+=3);
    }
    out[out.length-1] = in.substring(i, in.length());
```